# Parametric nonlinear term in mgcv

Tags: nonlinear-regression, splines, mgcv, nls

The R library `mgcv` can handle both **parametric linear** and **non-parametric non-linear** terms, but is there any way to let it handle **parametric non-linear** terms?

For example, say I had 3 continuous predictors of `y` that I wanted to model. Say that the effect of `x1` is linear, the effect of `x2` is "wiggly" (non-parametric, non-linear), and that the effect of `x3` is asymptotic (parametric non-linear, see `stats::SSasymp`). I'm imagining a model statement similar to:

`gam(y ~ x1 + s(x2) + SSasymp(x3,A,r,l), data = ...) # A,r,l = Initial values`

Are there other out-of-the-box solutions to this, or am I stuck writing a custom model in Stan or TMB?

Comment: There used to be a package for generalized nonlinear models (`gnm`) which I thought was really good (and into which it would have been possible to bring in spline terms without a lot of effort, I think), but last I saw some years ago it had stopped being maintained - really only a very short time after its original release, perhaps a couple of years. I haven't seen anything as comprehensive since.

Comment: @Glen_b, pity about that; looks like the last update was Feb 2020, but it might still work on older versions of R

Comment: If it was updated in 2020 that was more recent than I had seen - I gave up checking for updates prior to that. That's encouraging.

Answer (score 3):

I know of no way to make `gam()` optimize over external parameters, but you can avoid doing a ton of custom work by wrapping `gam()` in a call to `optim()`:

```r
# import mgcv
library( mgcv )

# import data and add a fake column
data(cars)
cars$a = 1:50

# create the wrapper function
wrap = function( par ) {
  m = gam( dist ~ s(a) + SSasymp( speed, par[1], par[2], 
           par[3] ), data=cars )

  # return the AIC (or whatever other summary you want to optimize over)
  AIC(m)
}

# do the optimization:
res = optim( c(1, 1, -10), wrap )
```

The result (the optimal parameters for `SSasymp()` are the converged `par` values):

```r
> res
$par
[1]   0.1971408   4.6114960 -12.6631887

$value
[1] 389.4047

$counts
function gradient 
     406       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Finally, you can fit the model at the converged values

```r
model = gam( dist ~ s(a) + SSasymp(speed, res$par[1], 
             res$par[2], res$par[3]), data=cars )
```

Comment: Looks like this works! I think that confidence intervals for the SSasymp parameters could be calculated by likelihood profiling or some kind of bootstrapping scheme, but both would take a large amount of time, so it's probably only worth it for smaller datasets.